# Alias to sudo gem --proxy <PROXY> or bash function?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, proxy

I have a script that I run when behind a proxy called proxy.sh which auto-sets various proxy settings such as:

- `http_proxy=<PROXY>`
- `https_proxy=<PROXY>`

Once I run this script I would love if it could auto-intercept the ruby `gem` command and add the proxy information as well:

`sudo gem install .....`  => `sudo gem install --http-proxy=<PROXY> ....`

At first I wanted to write an alias but I understand I need to actually make a function?  Is that correct?

How would I handle this?

If i run `proxy.sh` typing:  `sudo gem install TEST` would automatically run `sudo gem install --http-proxy=<PROXY> TEST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an alias. In `~/.bash_aliases` :

```
alias sudo="sudo "
alias gemproxy="gem install --http-proxy=<PROXY>"
```

The `sudo` alias (with a space) is important if you want to use the alias `gemproxy` with `sudo`.

EDIT : to intercept `gem install`, you can add this in your `.bash_aliases` :

```
gem() {
    if [[ $@ == install* ]]; then
        arg=${@#"install "}
        command gem install --http-proxy=PROXY $arg
    fi
}
```

But with this, you will always export the proxy even if you're not behind it. You can add a verification to see if the environment variable `http_proxy` is set.

Comment: This works but I really want to be able to intercept `sudo gem install` and auto-insert the proxy if i'm in proxy mode.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Maybe now it's what you want.

Comment: I wrapped this in: if [[ -z "$http_proxy" ]]; then and it all worked great